# is there any PyQt modul which is available for python 2?

Tags: pyqt, pip, pyqt5, pyqt4, python-2.x

i have a Toradex development board (Apalis iMX6q V1.1C
Ixora V1.1A
4.9.166 -2.8.6) and i want to use QT for application development for that i need PyQt..toradex has pip2 only and it is not having pip3 in its library..(for pip3 i have to do Custom image or to use Torizon,that i dont want) whenever i am trying to install PyQt from terminal it always showing requirement not satisfied whether it is PyQt4 or PyQt5..so i want to ask is there any PyQt module for python2 that i can install using pip2?

Comment: Try to look here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/ The last releases of PyQt4 for Python 2.7 are at https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/

Comment: There might perhaps be such a beast but frankly you would be shooting yourself in the foot because PyQt4 has been deprecated (no longer supported as of 2015) and Python2.x will be deprecated January next year.  Instead of trying to find a dinosaur that works with your dinosaur I would suggest finding a way to upgrade your dinosaur ;)